# What's the best way to handle nested static pages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**EDIT: Sorry, the title is a little unclear, I wanted to use 'semi-static' pages, using the render helper and ruby vars. The ERB templating system etc. Sorry guys! My fault!**

I've been looking into creating nested semi-static pages for a rails 3.1.3 app I'm building, and I've yet to find an answer that would suit all my needs. Any ideas?

All of the solutions I've come across are about creating *just* top level pages, like so:

```
- Site root
--- About (http://wwww.example.com/about)
--- Contact (http://wwww.example.com/contact)
--- Products (http://wwww.example.com/products)
--- Pricing (http://wwww.example.com/pricing
```

Whereas I'm looking to do something like

```
- Site root
--- About (http://wwww.example.com/about)
------ What we do (http://wwww.example.com/about/what-we-do)
------ Another sub-page (http://wwww.example.com/about/another-sub-page)
--- Contact (http://wwww.example.com/contact)
--- Products (http://wwww.example.com/products)
------ Product One (http://wwww.example.com/products/product-one)
------ Product Two (http://wwww.example.com/products/product-two)
--- Pricing (http://wwww.example.com/pricing)
```

I've come across solutions like mapping static controllers for each of the pages, but that doesn't seem like a particularly elegant solution.

Or creating a generic route and controller to match requests, like so:

```
in routes.rb:
map.connect '*path', :controller => 'content', :action => 'show'

in content_controller.rb:
def show
  render :action => params[:path].join('/')
end
```

But that seems even more inelegant, is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: I'm standing by my answer, and also calling this semi-static makes no sense. Like calling a girl a semi-virgin.

Comment: @pguardiario Semi-static makes perfect sense, as far as I'm aware. A page that contains content that's hardcoded but is constructed using various rails/ruby internal helpers like `render` for shared includes and internal asset management, for instance.

Comment: A page either is or is not static. It's a binary state. A one or a zero. There's no fuzzy math involved. In the situation you describe it is not static.

Answer (score 3):

> is there another way I'm missing?

Yes.

All you have to do is create static pages as you require in `/public,` either in the root of `public`, or in a directory structure.

A physical file existing at a path under `/public` should override any routes you configure to dynamically generated pages.

Comment: Thanks Dan. But I wanted to use the render helper so as not to violate DRY principles too much. I suppose the title is a little misleading, it should have read 'semi-static pages'. My apologies, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What DanSingerman said, but also... Just put your static pages on a separate fqdn, possibly hosted on a cdn. The only reason to have rails serve static assets is that you're being lazy and just can't be bothered doing it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem for static sub pages, came up with the following solution.

In routes.rb

```
match 'about/(:page)', :to => 'about#show', as: 'about'
match 'about/what-we-do', :to => 'about#show', as: 'what_we_do'
```

In about_controller.rb

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
  def show
    unless params[:page].blank?
      render "about/#{params[:page].underscore}"
    end
  end
end
```

In your views you can reference the alias paths.

```
<%= link_to 'About', about_path %>
<%= link_to 'What We Do', what_we_do_path %>
```

So `/about` will default to rendering the view `about.html.erb`.

But `/about/what-we-do` will render the view `about/what_we_do.html.erb`.

Would something like this help solve your problem?

Comment: Of course, you probably would want to add a check if the template exists. And could also DRY the solution by adding a helper method.

`def render_page
    unless params[:page].blank?
      render "#{params[:controller].downcase}/#{params[:page].underscore}"
    end
end`

Answer (score 0):

That is in fact what most CMS's do. If you feel that you are doing a lot of heavy lifting try plugging in a CMS like Refinery to your app. It makes life a little simpler by taking care of some of the SEO aspects. If you are interested in how Refinery CMS handles its pages, have a look at the [Pages Controller](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/pages/app/controllers/refinery/pages_controller.rb) and the related [routes](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/pages/config/routes.rb) and the [magic match all route](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/pages/lib/refinery/pages/engine.rb#L60).